# Search similar results

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

In my database, I will have college building rooms (such as B100, A200, TLAB100) and I want it so that when people search for a specific room (such as B101, B102) it will return the building name without the ending number, so: B100.

My controller so far looks like this:

```
$results = $this->Building->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Building.building LIKE' => $this->data['Food']['q']
        )
    )
);
```

But I believe LIKE isn't the right command for it. Because it's not working that way

Answer (score 0):

Why Like is not right?

```
$likeSmth = substr($this->data['Food']['q'], 0, -1);
'SELECT * FROM tbl  WHERE roomnumber LIKE '.$likeSmth.'%'
```

and etc.